# bitbucket authentication is failing

Tags: keychain, git

I keep my code in bitbucket.  Without warning  git pull just hangs and after a long wait says to check

1. Deleting all my keychain entries for bitbucket.org and relogging in manually didn't help anything.
2. Following the instructions for caching credentials didn't help either.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-Usingcredentialcaching

I can't find a git command for checking status of my authentication.
My login for bitbucket website works fine.

I'm on mac osx  10.11.5. El Capitan.

Comment: My issue was completely unrelated to git turns out.  The wifi I was on was blocking a port or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git config credential.https://example.com.username myusername` to update your credentials in Git and see if that helps. This is Git's documented way to avoid repeatedly being asked for your username and password.

Git's documentation for this: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials